# Stack too deep error in Solidity v0.8.4, no error / debug info from compiler

Tags: solidity, solc, solidity-0.8.x, stack

I have been facing the Stack too deep error, and it is being displayed without any line number / contract info. It is compiling all my contracts together (over 10) and I have no clue where this error is happening and how I am supposed to fix this. Any clues to make the compiler more verbose? I have already read through many of the posts talking about this, and I have worked on reducing local variables / moving to structs wherever possible, though it has not changed anything. I don't have a single function with over 7 parameters (and that one was compiling fine for a long time before this error appeared).

Any help will be much appreciated!!

I am using Solidity v0.8.4.

Comment: This is a good (relatively advanced) read, that may help -> https://medium.com/coinmonks/stack-too-deep-error-in-solidity-608d1bd6a1ea

Comment: I did go through this, although in my case I do not get a detailed error message so I don't know which line/contract the error is taking place. I don't think it is feasible or practical to debug 11 contracts to find the issue without any info on the error.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the issue was a struct to which I had added a few fields, and there were 16 fields in the struct, and that too is not permissible. Re-organizing, moving some fields to another struct, and having a struct within a struct seems to have solved the problem.